# JavaScript For loop not working after a certain line in the code

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, split, alert

I'm doing a simple exercise meant to be in JavaScript that consists of turning a binary into its respective decimal value... I feel I'm close to finishing the project but for some reason my for loops wont work after a certain line.

```
//function is called after the press of a button
function convertToBinary (){
    oText= document.all?document.all("inout"):document.getElementById("inout");
    //inout represents a textarea
    sText= oText.value;
    alert(sText);
    aText = sText.split(/\n\r|\n|\r/g); //got this line after searching this site for solutions

    /*alert(aText[1]);
    alert(aText[2]);
    alert(aText[3]);*/
```

aText does have values stored, checked a thousand times, but after this line everything goes down, and i can't seem to find the reason why. Here is the rest of the code copy/pasted from my text editor.

```
    for(y = 0; y < aText.lenght;y++){
        alert(aText[y]);
    }

    iCurrent=0;
    aBina= aText[0].split("");
    for(var x = aBina.lenght-1; x >= 0; x--){
        iCurrent = (iCurrent*2) + parseInt(aBina[x]);
        alert(iCurrent);
    }
    aAsci[0]=iCurrent;

    alert(iCurrent); //Alerts 0
 }
```

*NOTE: variables and arrays are properly defined in the first few lines of the code, i have used them in a previous function that does the opposite(convert decimals to binary) and that works fine. I was sure to clean each array and variable after the function is done. ("o" is for objects, "s" for strings, "a" for arrays, "i" for int's).*

There is no apparent syntax error to be seen. I would appreciate not posting the solution for the exercise unless it is really necessary, i might not be doing it right just yet but I like to think through the algorithms my self :p. My problem is for loops are as if the condition was not met, they are just being skipped. I'm using Opera Next as my web browser and the "inspect element" Console does not show any errors either.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have a typo in `lenght`. It should be `length`. Is that in the real code or a copying error here?

Comment: wait you say _"binary into its respective decimal value."_ but your function name is convetToBinary? which way are you going? if its to get a decimal you can just call parseInt with a radix of 2, unless this is for learning how to do it manually.

Comment: @Barmar G im tired... that IS a misspelling... ill just go to sleep now.

Answer (score 0):

This should be,

```
for(y = 0; y < aText.length;y++)
```

and this

```
for(var x = aBina.length-1; x >= 0; x--){
```

instead

```
for(var x = aBina.lenght-1; x >= 0; x--){
 for(y = 0; y < aText.lenght;y++)
```

you mispelled this one, "LENGTH"

Comment: You didn't fix the first misspelling :)

Comment: missed that one, sorry.